Clash between natbib and document calss revtex4-1
I am tring to write a lab report and the bibliography appears as an ecponent instead of [1]. I don't understand, here is my code if you guys have an idea ! I should also mention that i have tried with and without the \usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib} and nothing changed.
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,10pt,superscriptaddress,showpacs,showkeys]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Quantum Well Infrared Photodetector}

\author{Laure Thomarat}
\affiliation{Université Paris-Saclay, CNRS, Laboratoire de Physique des Solides, 91405, Orsay, France.}

\author{Timothée Tremblais}
\affiliation{Sorbonne Université, 4 Place Jussieu, 75005 Paris, France.}

\begin{abstract}
Work in progress:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Study the gain mechanism
    \item Perform fits of the curves
    \item Improve the visual presentation of figures
    \item Process the sample height data from the clean room
\end{itemize}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

During this practical, we tried to reproduce results from \cite{QWIP_GaAlAs}. This work consists of making an infrared detector based on a series of quantum wells. This work gave rise to a new field: the study of different heterostructures for QWIPs operating in the infrared domain. Modern research explores QWIPs for short, mid, and long wavelength infrared ranges \cite{Lattice-matched_AlInAs–InGaAs,The_opportunity_of_using_InGaAsN/AlGaAs_quantum_wells_for_extended_short-wavelength_infrared_photodetection}. Additionally, multi-band QWIPs have emerged, designed for use in focal plane arrays (FPAs)—essentially camera detectors for specific wavelengths \cite{Enhanced_performance_QWIP_FPAs}. QWIPs are extensively studied because they are cost-effective options for manufacturing infrared FPAs. Combined with their ability to cover the entire infrared spectrum, they are ideal candidates for creating infrared thermal cameras \cite{Measurements_of_very_small_temperature_variations_with_LWIR_QWIP_infrared_camera}.

\section{Creation of the Sample}

Content to be added.

\section{Characterization}

\subsection{Experimental Protocol}

\subsection{Energy Spectrum}

\subsection{IV Measurements}

\section{Discussion}

\section{Conclusion}

\newpage

\bibliography{biblio} % Nom du fichier .bib sans l'extension

\end{document}


clean up your preamble, epsfig is obsolete, inputenc is unneeded  and you don't need to load 4 color packages.

with revtex4-2 and without anything special I get this:
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,10pt,superscriptaddress,showpacs,showkeys]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}


blbl \cite{doody}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples} % Nom du fichier .bib sans l'extension

\end{document}



Thx, changing to 4-2 solved the problem :)

You need to (a) omit the instruction
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}

and (b) change
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}

to
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

i.e., drop the super option -- which, incidentally, is incompatible with the package's numbers option.
You should also drop the instruction \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} (as it's the default), not load latexsym, amsfonts, and epsfig, never load package's twice (cf inputenc, color, xcolor, gensymb), and quite simply reevaluate if you truly need all those other packages.

I reviewed a bit all thoses packages and i did not need all of them, I also got rid of the "super". But it did not solve the problem :(

@TimothéeTremblais -  your sample code is not compilable for anyone but you. Please simplify it and provide the bib entries needed to make it compilable.
